# Change Venmo profile pic to newer Facebook profile pic

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I set up my Venmo account with Facebook a while ago, and it successfully imported my Facebook profile picture to be my Venmo profile picture. I have since updated my Facebook profile picture, but my Venmo profile picture remains the same. The accounts are still connected.

Is it possible to update my Venmo profile picture automatically from Facebook without having to manually upload the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, Venmo does not update your Venmo profile picture when you update your Facebook profile picture, but you can manually change your profile picture using the link below:

https://venmo.com/account/settings/profile-picture

Don't hesitate to send me an email if you have any other questions regarding your Venmo account. Email me at support@venmo.com or send us a tweet @venmosupport.

Answer (score 0):

No. Many Facebook profile connections only pull information from Facebook on a need basis, e.g. when it needs to access your list of friends. Venmo must be one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If updating the photo manually through [Venmo settings](https://venmo.com/account/settings/profile-picture) as described by Adames, the photo cannot be a PNG file. JPEG files work.

Answer (score 0):

I found my way here after not being able to update my Venmo avatar. I found out that I could not upload any images in Chrome, but the mobile app did let me change my picture.

I am not a Facebook user these days, so that part does not apply to me even though that is perhaps how Venmo got my picture into Venmo originally.

The error message that I received in the developer console was:

```
"Photo was larger than 500kb"
```

This error message was received for images that were smaller than `500kb` and in the `JPEG` format.